# What is printf(), a statement or an expression? Why does it work with the ternary operator?

Tags: c, printf, conditional-operator

If the ternary operator asks for an expression, not a statement, then why does it compile `printf();`? Is `printf();` an expression or a statement?

Comment: Can you show a short code example where you illustrate your question? That would make it clearer for me.

Comment: It's a function, and has a return value (the number of printed values IIRC), so it can take part in an expression.

Comment: What is "ternary if" supposed to mean? Do you mean the conditional operator `?:`?

Comment: You cannot use `printf(`...`);` in a ternary expression; But you can use `printf(`...`)`. A function call is an expression; and one form of  statement is an expression followed by a semicolon.

Answer (score 6):

When you call a function (any function) it's an expression. When you add the terminating `;` you turn that expression into a statement.

In fact, you can turn any expression into a statement, by having the expression by itself, and add the statement terminator `;`. For example, all assignments are expression, so e.g.

```
a = b + c
```

is an expression, but

```
a = b + c;
```

is a statement.

It should also be noted that generally all expressions "returns" a value. In the case of the assignment expression it returns the value of the variable being assigned to (so in the example above, the assignment expression returns the value of `a` *after* the assignment has been made). That's how you can chain expressions together. In the example above, the statement is simply discarding the result of the assignment expression.

The only exception to expressions returning a value is function call expressions which call a function with a `void` return type. They don't have any result and can't be used in chained expressions.

---

Regarding the ternary expression, it takes three sub-expressions, evaluates the first and uses the result as a boolean to select which of the other two expressions should be evaluated.

Example:

```
a < b ? printf("a < b\n") : printf("a >= b\n");
```

The above line is a *statement*. The statement contains one expression, the ternary expression, and that expression contains three sub-expressions (the condition and the two function calls).

It's important to know that only *one* of the two branches of the ternary expression will be evaluated, so the above example will not call `printf` twice, only once.

Comment: Iek... my pet peeve, parameter-less `printf()` (that's what `puts()` is for). Otherwise, very good explanation, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Joachim's answer:

When you call the *function* `printf`, by itself it's an expression, where it returns a value based on the number of characters printed. However, one may discard this return value and be interested only in the *side-effect* of calling `printf` which is to print data to *stdout*.

When you do

```
a = b + c;
```

it means to evaluate the sub-expression `b + c` and then assign to it to `a` which also is an expression in C - it returns the value assigned to the left hand side; the `;` makes it into a statement.